# moving/sliding child window of screen causing more cpu usage

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a side toolbar window that slides out from the side of the main window.

The problem i'm having is that when its sliding in (hiding) it lags a tiny bit and is a little slower then when the window slides out, also causes the cpu to jump up more.

When the toolbar is sliding out it does not have this problem.

here is all the code that slides the window.

```
int ControllerToolbar::mouseMove(WPARAM state, int x, int y)
{
    // for tracking mouse hover/leave tracking
    if (!mouseHovered)
    {
        slideWindow(1);
        // mouse hover/leave tracking
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(tme);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
        tme.hwndTrack = handle;
        tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
        ::TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
        mouseHovered = true;
    }

    if (state == MK_LBUTTON)
    {
    }
    if (state == MK_RBUTTON)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}


int ControllerToolbar::mouseHover(int state, int x, int y)
{
    mouseHovered = true;
    return 0;
}


int ControllerToolbar::mouseLeave()
{
    mouseHovered = false;
    slideWindow(2);
    return 0;
}


void ControllerToolbar::GetToolbarPos(int *x, int *y) 
{
    RECT rect = { NULL };
    if (GetWindowRect(handle, &rect)) {

        MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, GetParent(handle), (LPPOINT)&rect, 2);

        *x = rect.left;
        *y = rect.top;
    }
}


void ControllerToolbar::slideWindow(int dir)
{
    std::thread([this, dir]
    {
        int x, y;
        GetToolbarPos(&x, &y);

        if (dir == 1)
        {
            while (x < 0 && mouseHovered)
            {
                x += 2;

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

                if (x > 0)
                    ::SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
                else
                    ::SetWindowPos(handle, 0, x, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
            }
        }
        else if (dir == 2)
        {
            while (x > -90 && !mouseHovered)
            {
                x -= 2;

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

                if (x < -90)
                    ::SetWindowPos(handle, 0, -90, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
                else
                    ::SetWindowPos(handle, 0, x, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);

            }
        }
    }
    ).detach();
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should not manipulate a window from a thread other than the thread that owns the window. A timer-based solution would solve this, and provide the ability to cancel the animation.